# Confidence interval

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

With

```
data = {{0.002, 2.51053}, {0.004, 2.54217}, {0.006, 2.55543}, {0.008, 2.54247}};
```

I obtain a linear fit `2.51038 + 5.454 x`; now I want to get the 95% confidence interval from linear regressions. when I do it with *Mathematica*, it gives me a pair of data set for the CI. I want to add the CI to `x -> 0.000717263`, but I don't know how to interpret that.

Comment: The size 4 of your data is too small to make reliable estimates, e.g. see https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_rationale_behind_the_magic_number_30_in_statistics .

Comment: Pay your attention to the result of `glm = GeneralizedLinearModelFit[data, x, x]`  `glm["ParameterTable"]`$$ \begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{z-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 1 & 2.51038 & 0.019372 & 129.588 & 0. \\
 x & 5.454 & 3.53682 & 1.54206 & 0.123058 \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
data = {{0.002, 2.51053}, {0.004, 2.54217}, {0.006, 2.55543}, {0.008, 2.54247}};

lm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x]

bands[x_] = lm["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> .95]

Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[{lm[x], bands[x]}, {x, 0, 0.01}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}], 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
bands[0.000717263]
```

> {2.44077, 2.58781}